# How can I create a model with different types in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to create a model Test with variables a, b, and c that responds to functions p, q, and r.  I'd like to create another model Supertest with variables a, b, c, d, and e that responds to functions p, q, r, s, and t.

Can I create one model Test and give it a type (regular or super) or must I create two types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to have one class inherit from another.

Here's an example from [rubylearning.com](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html)

```
class Mammal  
  def breathe  
    puts "inhale and exhale"  
  end  
end  

class Cat < Mammal  
  def speak  
    puts "Meow"  
  end  
end  

rani = Cat.new  
rani.breathe  
rani.speak
```